# Double reference to a table on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I was trying to add reference to two columns `birth_country_id` and `home_country_id`, which are related to `countries` table.

When I execute the following query it gives an error, `#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint`

```
ALTER TABLE `users` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `users_country_ids_foreign` 
    FOREIGN KEY 
        (`home_country_id`, `birth_country_id`) 
    REFERENCES `countries`(`id`, `id`) 
        ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

PS: This query is automatically generated by PhpMyAdmin.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate two seperate foreign keys. You want to individually check if the country you specified in `home_country_id` exists, and if the country you specified in `birth_country_id` exists.

MySQL does not support using the same column more than once in an index (which is the technical reason why your statement fails), but if it *would* be allowed, your foreign key would verify that `home_country_id` and `birth_country_id` are equal, which is probably not what you want to express.

Comment: The thing is that I don't have any data in any of my tables.

Comment: Put data in the tables then? Or is that too obvious of a solution? :P

Comment: @OzanKurt I am not sure what you mean. You do not need data in your tables to add a foreign key, although if you have data in `users`, you would need to have the countries that are assinged to all of your users too. Once you have the foreign key, and then insert/update a user with e.g. `home_country_id = 1`, MySQL will deny it if you do not have a row in table `countries` with `id=1`. (But again, I am not sure if that is what you meant, or if you are ware of that.). The important thing here is: you need two seperate constraints, not one with two columns.

Comment: Yes, that was what I ment. :D The error I was getting was without any columns. I instead did (col1, col2) references (ref1, ref2). So if you can update the answer it would be nice.

Comment: @OzanKurt `references (ref1, ref2)` is a completely different situation/question. It could best be answered if you would add the table structures (`show create table xxx`) for your two tables, as well as the (non-working) foreign key statement to a *new* question (although there are probably a lot of similar question for that more common scenario). The 2 most likely suspects: a) you do not have an index in your destination table that starts with `(ref1, ref2)` or b) the datatypes do not fit. (But as said before, that could best be answered by looking at your table structure).

Answer (score -1):

you can try adding 2 separate constraints for each columns in this case.